# PHP code shows as comment instead of executing. (Apache2, php7.0 and ubuntu 16.0.4)

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

My php code does not execute. Instead it is being sent as a comment. I have researched this issue for days and I believe I have everything correct. All the enable mods and confs are in place and I can run php from the command line. Just in apache2 it does not run. Note that it does not print the code as many people have had issues with. It just shows the code commented if I view the page source from the browser.

[image: See attached pic]

Any idea what could be causing this?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Paul, as I tried to explain, the code does not show up on the page in the browser. this is not the same issue.

Comment: I got it working. Had to modify the php7.0.conf file and uncomment the directive  "SetHandler application/x-httpd-php"
 between the first <FilesMatch></FilesMatch> (it was on line 2 of the file)  Hope this helps someone else who may have this same issue.